# Force Epiphany to open links in Chrome (in Gnome 3)

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, chrome

Chrome Web Apps don't get a separate dock icon in Gnome 3. A way around this is to use Epiphany for web apps, but the downside is that all links will open in a new Epiphany window.

**How can I have Epiphany Web App links to open in Chrome?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm entirely ignorant<sup>***</sup> about how Epiphany's "Web Apps" work, but [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/692462/comments/13) (of [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/692462)) illuminates how Chrome does it:

> what chromium does atm is just to find the browser desktop file, and use it as template for its webapps, by doing:
>
> - "Exec=" => updated to run the browser with the --app= flag
> - "Name=" => updated to match the webapp title
> - "GenericName", "Comment", "#" => dropped
> - "MimeType=" => dropped
> - "Icon=" => updated to use the site's favicon
> - everything else => copied vanilla.

Thus if you *found these files* and made GNOME Shell recognize them, you should also find their icons/starters in GNOME Shell's Application Menu (if that's what you're after, i.e. I didn't misunderstand your question).

*** Oh, look, they use [Desktop files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/1.0/ar01s05.html), [too](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-April/msg04783.html).

Comment: This doesn't actually help me. Despite the --app flag, and the .desktop file, Chrome groups all its application windows (on Gnome Shell, but not Unity -- which breaks alt-tab and window switching so is not a solution either :))

Comment: Oh.  Maybe [this helps](http://superuser.com/questions/394376/how-to-prevent-gnome-shells-alttab-from-grouping-windows-from-similar-apps)?

Answer (score 0):

This method will allow you to add separate dock icon in Gnome 3 for chrome web apps https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710?hl=en